# JavaScript Directing Stuck

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function direct() {
        location.href = "http://www.google.com/";

    }
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdirect" runat="server" OnClientClick="direct()">Home</asp:LinkButton>
```

I'm calling my js codes on OnClientClick but this button cannot direct to "google"

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: What happens when you click the LinkButton? Nothing like an error?

Comment: Google.com should open in same page -->something like directing

Comment: When I press LinkButton google.com should open in the same page.

Comment: Can you show the resulting markup instead of that ASP.net `LinkButton`?

Comment: I want to do this with "LinkButton".That's simple sample,When I click LinkButton my website should goes to google.com through javascript codes by "OnClientClick".

Comment: I'm clicking this button but page just postback and nothing gonna change :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the LinkButton is posting back to server the client side script never gets a chance to execute properly. You need to change your `OnClientClick` to return false:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkDirect" OnClientClick="direct();return false">Home</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function direct() {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";

    }
</script>
```